# Read text files with special format in python

Tags: python, text

I want to transform a folder of text documents in the following format:

`texts = ['text of document 1', 'text of document 2', 'text of document 3',...]`

in order to apply text mining methods.

So far my code is the following:

```
import os
file= "*.txt"
path = "C:\\"
texts=[]

for files in os.listdir(path):
     with open(path + files) as f:
         for x in f:
             texts.append(x)
```

Unfortunately, the outcome differs from the wanted one:

```
texts = ['line 1 of document 1', 'line 2 of document 1', …]
```

What am I doing wrongly? Can anybody suggest an improvement for my code?

Comment: So you want to read all the txt files in a folder and store their content in a list?

Comment: Yes, I already used f.read(), but then the list has empty entries:
texts = ['','','',...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for line in file:` (or in your case, `for x in f:`) iterates over the lines in a file.

Use the `.read()` method instead. That will read the entire file into a string:

```
for files in os.listdir(path):
     with open(path + files) as f:
         texts.append(f.read())
```

Edit: I just saw your comment about empty entries. If your directory contains empty files, you can prevent them from being added:

```
for files in os.listdir(path):
     with open(path + files) as f:
         contents = f.read()
         if contents.strip(): # will also remove files that contain only whitespace
             texts.append(f.read())
```